# Browser issue for firebase cloud messging

Tags: javascript, safari, firebase-cloud-messaging

using firebase messaging.It works on chrome, firefox but not working on Microsoft edge and safari browser.

> The error raised in the console is : **FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).**

what i'm getting wrong code is:

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
var resp = JSON.parse(payload.data.notification);
var board_id = resp.boardId;
  var notificationTitle = resp.title;
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: resp.body,
    icon: resp.icon
  };})
```

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. Firebase Cloud Messaging is not supported in Safari, since it doesn't support the Push API. See https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555067/push-notifications-in-apple-safari-with-fcm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push notifications in Apple Safari with FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555067/push-notifications-in-apple-safari-with-fcm)

Comment: Thanks for response. is there any other solution

Comment: @SohailAhmad Have you got solution ?