# Angular using FCM and white screen in safari browser

Tags: angular, browser, safari, firebase-cloud-messaging

I used FCM in a PWA Angular project even though my host is set to HTTPS, but it doesn't work in the Safari browser and shows a white screen.
This also works in other browsers (Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera).

Comment: FCM does not work in Safari. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555067/push-notifications-in-apple-safari-with-fcm

Comment: Are there any other push notifications that all browsers support?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
I don`t think so,
I have another app that i used FCM and it's normally work in Safari.
https://app.bepors.me

Comment: If that's the case it clearly can work, and the problem must be in the difference between the two apps. We can't help without seeing the problem, so I recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Following the guidance in there is the best way to maximize the chances that someone can help with code-related problems.