# React Native. Firebase. Push notifications using Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

My RN mobile app works with Firebase as a Web App. Everything works fine. Now I need to add the push notifications functionality to my mobile app. I have read several articles about push notifications for RN apps:

- https://blog.logrocket.com/react-native-push-notifications-firebase-cloud-messaging/
- https://medium.com/alameda-dev/react-native-push-notifications-with-firebase-d23ed0dfb3ae
- https://enappd.com/blog/firebase-push-notifications-in-react-native/81/

Mainly all articles describe a specific configuration for Android.

My question is, can I use web push notifications in my mobile RN app as described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client ? Or should I register a separate application for Android and iOS in my Firebase project and add to my RN project platform-specific files (AndroidManifest.xml, google-services.json, build.gradle, etc)?

[Firebase apps screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqmNP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Web SDK, push notifications will not arrive on iOS as the Safari/WebKit implementation there doesn't support the necessary APIs that Firebase Cloud Messaging depends on. See [Push notifications in Apple Safari with FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555067/push-notifications-in-apple-safari-with-fcm) for more on this.

Comment: Frank, thank you for your answer. I meant for my mobile app, can I use the web setup and expect push notifications to come to Android and iOS? Or do I need a separate configuration for Android and iOS?

Comment: I understood your question, and that's what I answered: it won't work on iOS as Safari/WebKit there doesn't support the required APIs. Configuration will not help for that.